# Android catch two fingers tap on MapView

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, gesture, pinch

In my code I want to add zoom in on double-tap and zoom out on two-fingers-tap (like Google Maps). I'm using this code:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new DoubleTapDetector());
touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        final int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        final int fingersCount = motionEvent.getPointerCount();

        if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) && (fingersCount == 2)) {
            onTwoFingersTap();

            return false;
        }

        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
};
```

Double-tap works fine, but when I trying to pinch map, it zoom as usual but zoom out by one step because of `onTwoFingersTap();` is catched too.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return true if your condition is satified:

```
    touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {    
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {    
        final int action = motionEvent.getAction();       
        final int fingersCount = motionEvent.getPointerCount();        
        if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) && (fingersCount == 2)) {             
            onTwoFingersTap();       
            return true;         
        } 
     return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);     
    } 
 };
```

Comment: If I change return value to True, something strange happens - MapView became white and markers on map shift are chaotically moving

Comment: That is strange. Returning true will just tell android not to process the onToucheEvent any furthur. Maybe you are doing something wrong in onTwoFingersTap();

Comment: Yes, somethings strange happens. I too tried this, map turns white and markers moves..